# how to convert xml into KSOAP request?

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap

I am new to android.I have a xml which shows the details to be sent on the server through SOAP,so please tell me how to convert the following xml in KSOAP request.Thanks

```
<location>
<locationId>132</locationId>
<name>test</name>
<qualifiedCoordinates>
<altitude>10</altitude>
</qualifiedCoordinates>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
    request.addProperty("locationId", 132);
    request.addProperty("name", test);
    request.addProperty("altitude", 10);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();}
catch(Exception e) {
        tempText.setText("Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but one doubt,'altitude' is defined in 'qualifiedQoordinats'so will it be correct to directly add as property to request.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but most probably yes. The only way to know to it try it out and see if it gives any error.

Comment: Oh, okay. Tough luck then. What you can do is either change the format of your xml and remove the <qualifiedCordinates> tag and make things easier. Or, if you cant change the web service then you would have to create your own class of Location and marshal it before sending.

Comment: These links might help you. http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29305/Consuming-NET-Web-Services-via-the-kSOAP-library